# Android Asset Studio: Creating icons with an image does not work

Tags: android

Is anyone else having this problem? http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html When i try to use an image and i upload the image it just turns out to be a grey box. I have tried in all different browsers and still no luck.

Comment: Any solution for your question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have one of two issues.

1) To verify if the image is getting processed, make sure you select 'Launcher Icons' from the main screen as a test. **Other icons are not full color**, they are Grey or black or white. For Example, the icons for the Action Bar are supposed to be Grey (depending on theme). See the [action bar design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html). If you see your icon, but it is square instead of it's native 'shape' you have the second issue.

2) Use gif (or png) as your original and make sure you set the transparent color when you created it.

Answer (score 1):

The tool works well for me in several browsers. I suggest you try a different browser, and make sure your bitmap isn't corrupt.

Comment: Is there a certain image format that you use? i have tried .bmp .png .jpg non seem to be working.

Comment: I normally use it with PNG. The code runs in the client, so what browser you're using is critical to whether it'll work or not. I use it in Chrome on windows. If you still have problems submit a bug report to Roman Nurik so it can get fixed.